# What should I use to patch curved surfaces over horse hair plastered lath?

Tags: repair, lath-and-plaster

The hallway running into my condo is unsightly.  However, the association is saving for some structural work, and thus the hallway aesthetics have been put on the back burner.

Typically I'd run out and fix small cracks when I have a jar of spackle open, but have noticed that it doesn't stick well because the horse hair plaster is so soft and dry, moreover, for larger holes spackle with large contours, spackle doesn't seem to want to be shaped.

In general the horse hair plaster seems so weak that I'm guessing it should all be removed and replaced with veneer plaster, but I'll leave that for the association to undertake.

### What is the best material for repairing contorted horse hair plaster?

Comment: I've always done fine with just cleaning out the looser material and using joint compound and fiberglass tape. The only thing I've found spackling worth using on are small nail holes.

Comment: okay, I'll try joint compound tomorrow.